# I want to connect duplicates in a 2-dimensional array

Tags: python

Python.
There is a two-dimensional array called lines, and this is an example:

```
lines = [[0,1],[0,2],[0,3],[1,4],[1,5],[2,6],[3,7],[3,8],[3,9]].
```

In this case, `lines[0][0]`, `lines[1][0]`, and `lines[2][0]` overlap. In addition, the values of `lines[0][1]` and `lines[3][0]`,`lines[4][0]` are also duplicated, so we want to do the following.

I would like to eventually have this output as `[0,[1,[4],[5]],[2,[6]],[3,[7],[8],[9]]]`, but I cannot think of a way.

I'm trying to loop using a for statement, but I can't get the index right, so I get IndexError: list index out of range. I want to create a new list called `line_l` and have `line_l = [0,[1,[4],[5]],[2,[6]],[3,[7],[8],[9]]]`.

Python

```
lines = [[0,1],[0,2],[0,3],[1,4],[1,5],[2,6],[3,7],[3,8],[3,9]]
line_l = []
i= 0
j = 0

for i in range(len(lines)):
    for j in range(len(lines)):  
        if lines[i][0] == lines[j][0]:                
            line_l.append([lines[j][i]])
　　　　　　  j += 1
        else:
            j+=1
     i += 1
print(line_l)
```

When I run this, I get an error at line_l.append([lines[j][i]]).
We think that i is probably the reason why the loop does not go all the way to the end.

Comment: Can you explain more about how you get from these identified duplicates to that desired output. I follow your explanation, right up until you drop that `[0,[1,[4],[5]],[2,[6]],[3,[7],[8],[9]]]` output. I can't figure out how these dups lead to that thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reason of error is adding one unit to `i` and `j` in every step of loop (we don't need this operation because of using loop).

This code works for you:

```
lines = [[0,1],[0,2],[0,3],[1,4],[1,5],[2,6],[3,7],[3,8],[3,9]]
line_l = []

for i in lines:
  element = list()
  for j in lines:  
    if i[0] == j[0]:   
      element.append(j[1])
  new_element = [i[0], element]
  if new_element not in line_l:
    line_l.append(new_element)
print(line_l)


# [[0, [1, 2, 3]], [1, [4, 5]], [2, [6]], [3, [7, 8, 9]]]
```